# My main contribution as a first author eventually diminished over multiple rejection cycles. Can I still state it in my research statement?

Tags: phd, application, authorship, research-statement

A paper I lead from inception contained two major components. Unfortunately, the reviewers insisted that we focus on just one of them, and a decision was made to focus less on the component that I worked on.

Eventually, due to page limitations and overall coherence of the paper, the component was dropped from the final revision. Since I've been involved in the writing throughout, I am still the first co-author. However, I do not own the main component of the paper, which has been accepted for publication.

Currently I am in the process of applying to grad schools and was wondering if I can include details of that component in my research statement.

Additionally, should I also describe the story of why it doesn't exist in the final version?

Comment: You probably have an opportunity for another paper, actually.

Comment: @Buffy that's true, but I can't it done before the application cycle! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I know it is that in your research statement you are meant to focus on what you are planning to do in the future or currently doing, not what your contribution to past papers is, but this may be different in some places I don't know.

Regarding writing down what you did in the past, you can honestly mention the paper and what you actually worked on. I don't think you need to explicitly say that this didn't find the way into the final version; people will not normally read your research statement against the actual paper, and even if they do and somebody raises an issue (which I think is unlikely), you can clarify in an interview what happened. If you don't have to explicitly mention what you worked on there, don't do it. You could let the reference speak for itself (even though it does so maybe in a slightly misleading manner;-).

Comment: The first paragraph is key here. The paper belongs in the CV, not the research statement (or the SoP if required). Write about your research trajectory, not the past.